# Scala play-json - doesn't parse/deserialize to single argument case class

Tags: json, scala, parsing, play-json

In Scala, I want to parse JSON responses retrieved using the Travis CI REST API. For that, I've decided to use the play-json library. Along with this, and in accordance to the REST API 'schema', I've defined the following case classes:

```
case class Build(id : Int,
             repository_id : Int,
             commit_id : Int,
             number : String,
             event_type : String,
             pull_request : Boolean,
             pull_request_title : String,
             pull_request_number : String,
             state : String,
             started_at : String,
             finished_at : String,
             duration : Int,
             job_ids : List[Int]) extends Serializable{
}

case class Builds(builds : List[Build])
```

The implementation should be self-explanatory by itself, but if any further description is required, I'll update the question.

Along with this, I've defined the following Reads for the play-json library:

```
implicit val buildReads : Reads[Build] = (
      (JsPath \ "id").read[Int] and
      (JsPath \ "repository_id").read[Int] and
      (JsPath \ "commit_id").read[Int] and
      (JsPath \ "number").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "event_type").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "pull_request").read[Boolean] and
      (JsPath \ "pull_request_title").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "pull_request_number").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "state").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "started_at").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "finished_at").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "duration").read[Int] and
      (JsPath \ "job_ids").read[List[Int]]
    )(Build.apply _)

implicit val buildsReads : Reads[Builds] = (__ \ "builds").read[List[Build]].map(Builds(_))
```

The code does compile, the schema i.e. the case classes do confirm to the REST API response, however, when validating the response, I get the following error:

JsError(List((/builds(0)/pull_request_title,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsstring),WrappedArray()))), (/builds(0)/pull_request_number,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsstring),WrappedArray()))), (/builds(1)/pull_request_title,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsstring),WrappedArray()))), (/builds(1)/pull_request_number,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsstring),WrappedArray()))), (/builds(2)/pull_request_title,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsstring),WrappedArray()))), (/builds(2)/pull_request_number,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsstring),WrappedArray()))), (/builds(3)/pull_request_title,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsstring),WrappedArray()))), (/builds(3)/pull_request_number,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsstring),WrappedArray()))), (/builds(4)/pull_request_title,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsstring),WrappedArray()))), (/builds(4)/pull_request_number,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsstring),WrappedArray()))), (/builds(5)/pull_request_title,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsstring),WrappedArray()))), (/builds(5)/pull_request_number,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsstring),WrappedArray()))), (/builds(6)/pull_request_number,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsstring),WrappedArray()))), (/builds(7)/pull_request_title,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsstring),WrappedArray()))), (/builds(7)/pull_request_number,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsstring),WrappedArray()))), (/builds(8)/pull_request_title,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsstring),WrappedArray()))), (/builds(8)/pull_request_number,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsstring),WrappedArray()))), (/builds(9)/pull_request_title,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsstring),WrappedArray()))), (/builds(9)/pull_request_number,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsstring),WrappedArray()))), (/builds(10)/pull_request_title,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsstring),WrappedArray()))), (/builds(10)/pull_request_number,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsstring),WrappedArray()))), (/builds(11)/pull_request_number,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsstring),WrappedArray()))), (/builds(12)/pull_request_title,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsstring),WrappedArray()))), (/builds(12)/pull_request_number,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsstring),WrappedArray()))), (/builds(13)/pull_request_title,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsstring),WrappedArray()))), (/builds(13)/pull_request_number,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsstring),WrappedArray()))), (/builds(14)/pull_request_title,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsstring),WrappedArray()))), (/builds(14)/pull_request_number,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsstring),WrappedArray()))), (/builds(15)/pull_request_title,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsstring),WrappedArray()))), (/builds(15)/pull_request_number,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsstring),WrappedArray()))), (/builds(16)/pull_request_number,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsstring),WrappedArray()))), (/builds(17)/pull_request_number,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsstring),WrappedArray()))), (/builds(18)/pull_request_title,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsstring),WrappedArray()))), (/builds(18)/pull_request_number,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsstring),WrappedArray()))), (/builds(19)/pull_request_title,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsstring),WrappedArray()))), (/builds(19)/pull_request_number,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsstring),WrappedArray()))), (/builds(20)/pull_request_title,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsstring),WrappedArray()))), (/builds(20)/pull_request_number,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsstring),WrappedArray()))), (/builds(21)/pull_request_number,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsstring),WrappedArray()))), (/builds(22)/pull_request_title,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsstring),WrappedArray()))), (/builds(22)/pull_request_number,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsstring),WrappedArray()))), (/builds(23)/pull_request_title,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsstring),WrappedArray()))), (/builds(23)/pull_request_number,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsstring),WrappedArray()))), (/builds(24)/pull_request_title,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsstring),WrappedArray()))), (/builds(24)/pull_request_number,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsstring),WrappedArray())))))

Any clue onto what the problem might be? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide the sample JSON that is triggering the error (preferably smaller than what triggered the error above, because it looks like a huge array).

Comment: @m-z Issue resolved - the problem was that the pull_request field : Boolean indicates whether the build was made via a pull request or not - meaning that the pull_request_title and pull_request_number can have null values. The fix was to do the following: (JsPath \ "pull_request_title").read[String].orElse(Reads.pure(null))

Comment: I would recommend using `Option[String]` rather than `null`, then you could use `readNullable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With play Json if the case class which you intend to serialize is not using any custom types you don't need to hand write your readers or writers, you can use the Json.Writes[T]:

```
implicit val buildFormat = Json.Reads[Build]
```

This will automatically generate the Reads for you (you can also use Json.Writes[T] or Json.Format[T]). Play is clever enough to be able to use this to deserialize a List[T] also.